# Are there any event (whether micro or macro) with only one possible outcome?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, quantum-interpretations

I'm honestly confused with how quantum mechanics works. Does the double-slit experiment indicate all events have more than one possible outcome? If that's the case, does a single-slit that shows no interference mean that there's only one outcome for a single electron?

(Which means determinism because there is a designated outcome?)

Comment: this is relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/313180/

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible outcomes in the DSE means that if a single photon/electron is directed thru the slits to a screen that it will take probable paths (some paths more probable than others) and this will form the pattern.  In the dark areas there are no photons, in the bright all with the central peak having the most.  Feynman proposed the path integral to calculate the probability pattern on the screen.  We cannot say which path until we see it ... but we can place pretty good bets on where they are likely to show up!

Even with a single slit there is a pattern .... i.e there are probable paths due to the wave nature of the photon/electron.  Feynman showed that path length is an important factor in the path's probability.

If we emit many photons each will determine its own probable path to the screen, if the source is small the pattern is strong.

Comment: That's a good point, that there is a distribution pattern even behind single slits. And that the word interference is not mentioned, because it is not..